# How to create events in Obj-c via code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have one `UIButton` and i need to create event `Touch up inside` how i can to create this event no using IB in implementation file `.m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick....

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Incidentally, there are literally hundreds of posts on the internet for creating buttons manually - a fair number of them are on here too.  Try searching for "create button manually" or "create button programmatically".

Comment: Remember to mark as answered if correct, or a useful answer if that's more appropriate.  Cheers,